# Factory method for generic interface

Tags: c#-4.0, factory-pattern

I think this code is mortally wounded but would like some opinions before I take a new approach.

I am writing a factory method for the following interface.

```
public interface ITransformer<I, O>
{
   O Transform(I input);
}
```

Here is a possible implementation of the interface

```
public class CarToTruckTransformer : ITransformer<Car, Truck>
{
    public Truck Transform(Car input)
    {
        Truck output = new Truck();
        output.Seats = input.Seats - 2;
        output.BedSize = input.TrunkSize;
        output.Gunrack = true;
        return output;
    }
}
```

The first factory I did looks like this

```
static class TransformerFactory
{
    public static ITransformer<I, O> GetTransformer<I, O>()
    {
        if (typeof(I) == typeof(Car) && typeof(O) == typeof(Truck))
        {
            return (ITransformer<I, O>)new CarToTruckTransformer();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
       }
    }
}
```

But I have to know the exact types when I call the factory method so it seems less than ideal.

```
ITransformer<Car, Truck> transf = TransformerFactory.GetTransformer<Car, Truck>();
```

I have also toyed with the following, but I'm afraid this may be a gross misuse of the dynamic keyword.

```
public class TransformerFactory2
{
    public static dynamic GetTransformer(VehicleBase input, VehicleBase output)
    {
        if (input.GetType() == typeof(Car) && output.GetType() == typeof(Truck))
        {
            return (ITransformer<Car, Truck>)new CarToTruckTransformer();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But it does allow me to get the factory syntax that I want.

```
dynamic transf = TransformerFactory2.GetTransformer(car, truck);
```

I've also considered the first option but calling the factory method with reflection so I could dynamically assign the type variables.

Ultimately, I would like the entire "transform" process to be contained in one reusable method and just implement new transformers when needed but I'm not there yet.
Is there a better or safer approach for this kind of situation?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This is the kind of problem that is best solved by a dependency injection library like Ninject. These libraries allow you to easily bind concrete implementations to an interface and then your factory can easily get the proper implementation at execution time.

Answer (score 0):

This is way off topic if you are interested in exploring OOP and Patterns but this specific example you are describing can be fairly neatly described using `Func<I,O>` delegates.

e.g.

```
var car = getSomeCar();
car.select(c => new Truck{
   :
   :
});
```

And you define `select` as a generic extension method on `I`

e.g.

```
public static O select<I,O>(this I input, Func<I,O> project)
{
   return project(input);
}
```

Just a thought.

**Edit**

Just tested this and it should work fine :)
Renamed `transform` to `select` to highlight the similarity to the Linq operator.

Comment: I like the idea.  I will give it a try.